# r raster how to vectorize a function to use with overlay

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to do a raster overlay that uses this function where x and y are rasters and Tbase is a constant.

```
gddFunction <- function(x, y, z) {(x + y)/2 - z}
```

like this

```
library(raster)
gdd <- overlay(x = tmax_clamped, y = tmin_clamped, z = Tbase, fun = gddFunction)
```

I get the following error message

> Error in (function (x, fun, filename = "", recycle = TRUE, forcefun =
>   FALSE,  :    cannot use this formula, probably because it is not
>   vectorized

I tried following the examples in Help, as follows

```
 vgddFunction <- Vectorize(gddFunction, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
 gdd <- overlay(x = tmax_clamped, y = tmin_clamped, z = Tbase, fun = vgddFunction)
```

but got the same error message.

I suspect the problem is that I need z to be a vector of constant values or maybe a raster layer of constant values. But I was hoping the Vectorize operation would do that.

Straightforward map algebra works, as in

```
gdd <- (x + y)/2 - z
```

but its slow and I was hoping to speed up the calculation by using overlay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raster::overlay` only allows `raster` arguments to be passed as extra arguments through the `...` (see `?overlay`). So you can't do directly what are doing now. But we can avoid that problem. A reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
r1 <- init(r, fun = runif)
r2 <- init(r, fun = runif)
z <- 3
```

Your error:

```
gddFunction <- function(x, y, z) {(x + y)/2 - z}
gdd <- overlay(x = r1, y = r2, z = z, fun = gddFunction)
```

> ```
> Error in (function (x, fun, filename = "", recycle = TRUE, forcefun = FALSE,  : 
>   cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized
> ```

If we can't pass `z` directly, we can pass it indirectly with some functional programming:

```
gddFunction2 <- function(z) {
  function(x, y) (x + y) / 2 - z
}
gdd <- overlay(x = r1, y = r2, fun = gddFunction2(z))
```

Here, `gddFunction2` will return another function that only has an `x` and `y` argument that can take the `rasters`, but you can still change the constant `z`, which is now an argument to `gddFunction2`.

You could also write that as:

```
gddFunction <- gddFunction2(z)
gdd <- overlay(x = r1, y = r2, fun = gddFunction)
```

Note that your original `gddFunction` is already vectorized, so that error message is guessing at the problem incorrectly.

Comment: I've tried three approaches - straight map algebra (gdd <- `(x + y)/2 - z`, creating a raster layer with row, col dimensions of x and y and a constant value, and your approach. The map algebra took 686 sec, the straight overlay with the raster z took 274 seconds (not including creating the z layer), and your approach is 280 seconds. It's definitely the overall winner! Thanks!